# Regular expression to find misspelled words, changing group order

Tags: regex, regex-group

The task I'm trying to accomplish is crawling a list of web pages and see if there are any common misspellings on said pages.

Here's where I stuck.

I'm using this RegEx (\W|^)(therefor|wich|sence)(\W|$)
Which finds misspelled words from this string:
**therefor**, therefore, which, **wich** whichita, presence , **sence**, sence
and ignores words where misspellings are part of another word

[regex test screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJB2T.png)

Problem is, results (words) are moved to the second capturing group and parser I'm using only shows results from 1st group.

So I can see that certain page has one of the misspellings, but I don't know which one since it's in group 2.

Is there a way to change the order of groups in RegEx?

PS: using something else to find misspelled words is not an option, I need to be able to perform this task with a scraper I use.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does you engine support `\b` word boundary? Use `\b(therefor|wich|sence)\b`

Comment: Do you have to use regular expressions when there are spell checking libraries available?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes. this seems to be it, guess I was overthinking it. I tried (\b) in brackets creating an unnecessary group, don't even know why.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Of course `(...)` creates a group. Any pair of matching unescaped parentheses creates a group (if it is not a POSIX BRE pattern)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew \b has a flaw. it doesn't work if the line starts with a misspelled word. but it got me thinking and I turned first and last groups into non-capturing groups with ?: 
(?:\W|^)(therefor|wich|sence)(?:\W|$)
in case you'll need a similar solution

Comment: You are wrong. `\bw` will match `w` at the start of the line or after a non-word char.